# How to convert a .py to .exe if i want to include many subfolders and imported modules in the final executable?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, py2exe

I have developed a project which has the following structure :

```
web_app
└── website
|   ├── __init__.py
|   ├── auth.py
|   ├── models.py
|   ├── views.py
|   ├── static
|   │   ├── images
|   │   │   └── logo_kg.png
|   │   ├── app.js
|   │   ├── index.js
|   │   └── styles.css
|   └── templates
|       ├── base.html
|       ├── home.html
|       ├── login.html
|       ├── sign_up.html
|       └── viewProjects.html
└── main.py
```

I want to convert my main.py to an executable in order to distribute it easily without the need of the client to have python installed on his system. I want to embed all the imported modules of my project and its subfolders (based on the project structure) into one executable file.

All the imported modules i have are :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for
from .models import User
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from . import db
from flask_login import login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user
from website import create_app
from . import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, flash, jsonify
from flask_login import login_required, current_user
from .models import Project
from . import db
import json
import base64
from sqlalchemy import func
```

#### Some of the commands i tried

I tried running commands like :

```
pyinstaller --add-data "website/static;static" --add-data "website/templates;templates" --hidden-import flask,flask_sqlalchemy,flask_login,werkzeug.security,sqlalchemy.sql,sqlalchemy,flask_login.mixins,flask_login.utils,flask_login.config,flask_login.signals,flask_login.view,flask_login.login_manager --hidden-import website.models,website.db,json,base64 --onefile website/main.py
```

but upon running the generated .exe i was met with the localhost page displaying :

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

and the console showing the following errors :

```
Created Database!
ERROR:website:Exception on /login [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flask\app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
  File "flask\app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
  File "flask\app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
  File "flask\app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
  File "auth.py", line 26, in login
  File "flask\templating.py", line 150, in render_template
  File "jinja2\environment.py", line 1081, in get_or_select_template
  File "jinja2\environment.py", line 1010, in get_template
  File "jinja2\environment.py", line 969, in _load_template
  File "jinja2\loaders.py", line 126, in load
  File "flask\templating.py", line 64, in get_source
  File "flask\templating.py", line 98, in _get_source_fast
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: login.html
```

I don't really know how to proceed with generating one executable that will have embedded all the project structure and include the referenced imports.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a spec file to manage pyinstaller properly.

```
# main.spec

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['<path_to_your_project>'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('<path_to_your_project>/website/static', 'static'),
                    ('<path_to_your_project>/website/templates', 'templates')],
             hiddenimports=['flask', 'flask_sqlalchemy', 'flask_login', 'werkzeug.security', 'sqlalchemy.sql', 'sqlalchemy', 'flask_login.mixins', 'flask_login.utils', 'flask_login.config', 'flask_login.signals', 'flask_login.view', 'flask_login.login_manager', 'website.models', 'website.db', 'json', 'base64'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True)
```

Save that as main.spec and run
`pyinstaller main.spec`

Comment: i get the following error :
```
Created Database!
ERROR:website:Exception on /login [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flask\app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
  File "flask\app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
  File "flask\app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
  File "flask\app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
  File "website\auth.py", line 26, in login
  File "flask\templating.py", line 150, in render_template
  File "jinja2\environment.py", line 1081, in get_or_select_template
[more errors]
```
why is that?

Comment: Can you show the code for render_template?

Comment: render_template is a submodule of flask module.
I am importing it like this : "from flask import Blueprint, render_template" in some of the other python scripts that i showed in my project structure.

Comment: I meant, can you show where you are using render_template

Comment: In my views.py and in my auth.py. I use them like 'return render_template("home.html", user=current_user)'